# Firebase: how to get data snapshot without to use an event?

Tags: firebase

I would like to know how can I take an snapshot without using an event.

After to check the documentation and examples I couldn't find how to do that.

Suppose I have this:

```
var refRoom = refRoom.toString();
newRefRoom = new Firebase(refRoom);
newRefRoom.update({Marker1:"YES"});
newRefRoom.update({Marker2:"YES"});
```

How can I, for instances, to get the contents of Marker1? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
var mycontent = newRefRoom.Marker1.val();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use the on value event?

Comment: Please try out [Getting Started](https://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html) and the [Tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted)